# Check whether the number in a range is a prime number, if not, return all factors

Tags: python, for-loop, break, continue

Let's say we want to look at range(2,10).

I have written the following code:

```
for n in range(2,10):
    for x in range(2,n):
        if n%x == 0:
            print(n,'equals',x,'*',n//x)  
            break
    else:
        print(n, "is a prime number")
```

The above way can do checking correctly but it also returns one factor.

But if I replace break to continue:

```
for n in range(2,10):
    for x in range(2,n):
        if n%x == 0:
            print(n,'equals',x,'*',n//x)  
            continue
    else:
        print(n, "is a prime number")
```

It couldn't do the checking correctly anymore. So is there any better way to get both checking and all factors correctly? 
Your answer will be of great help to me!!

Comment: Side note, you only need the second loop to test numbers until square root of N

Answer (score 1):

Do not use either break or continue, but make and use a bool variable `prime` as follows.

```
for n in range(2,10):
    prime = True
    for x in range(2, n):
        if n%x == 0:
            print(n,'equals',x,'*',n//x)  
            prime = False
    if prime:
        print(n, "is a prime number")
```